# postgreSQL does this help improve performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say i have a social media app where users can post and for each post i'm  inserting a row to the posts table, and updating the user_affiliates table.

Now lets say that the user wants to see all of his/her posts what's the most efficient way to select posts that the user has posted?

This is a simplified version of my database:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id serial UNIQUE,
    user_id VARCHAR (100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    register_date bigint NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE user_affiliates(
    id serial UNIQUE,
    user_id VARCHAR (100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    int_posts integer default 0, --holding number of posts that the user made
    posts text[] --holding all post_ids (posts that the user made) 
    
);
CREATE TABLE posts(
    id serial UNIQUE,
    user_id VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    post_id VARCHAR (100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    post_body varchar NOT NULL,
    post_date bigint NOT NULL
);
```

Currently i'm selecting posts from the array in user_affiliates table:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts pp
JOIN user_affiliates u ON pp.post_id = ANY(u.posts)
WHERE u.user_id = 'user1'
```

Is that the best way to do it? or just simply selecting from posts table like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts where user_id = 'user1'
```

Keep in mind  there is going to be  hundreds of thousands  of rows inserted into posts table and tens of thousands of rows inserted into user_affiliates.

And also i'm going to do have many more tables (user_videos,user_replies,user_likes) and i need to do the same thing...

So does the user_affiliates table make any sense? or does it help with performance?what about holding number of posts in int_posts does that help with performance instead of counting each post from posts?

Thanks for answering and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: You should ad primary keys and foreign keys to your data model.

Comment: `posts text[]` -- consider normalizing your database model. This is not even 1NF.

Comment: *posts text[] --holding all post_ids* - don't do this, have a table with one row per post_Id for each user_id.

Comment: @TheImpaler so if i add  primary keys and foreign keys i should stick with the first method?

Comment: @AlandSleman My impression is that you are modeling users and their posts. I would have expected two tables instead of three. I don't understand the relationship for the second and third tables.

Comment: @TheImpaler user_affiliates table simply is going to hold information about the user like their posts,videos etc... so for posts array i thought it would be faster to select post_id S from that array rather than selecting from posts table directly

Comment: @AlandSleman The lack of PKs and FKs, in addition to the extra/costly redundancy for read operations tend to reveal that you are trying to implement a NoSQL model in a relational database. It can be done that way, but relational databases usually do it in a different way, placing mode emphasis in data quality, than extreme performance.

Comment: @TheImpaler i was going to add PKs and FKs but im new to postgres so i've recently learned about them i didn't implement it yet

Comment: @TheImpaler so what you suggesting is to get rid from user_affiliates and simply add PKs and FKs and use the second method(selecting from posts table directly)?

Comment: @AlandSleman Yes, that makes sense. The extreme performance that can be produced by the extra table can come useful at some point, nevertheless. However, it's too early to adopt such a solution. The simpler alternative you describe is probably more than enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lose the `user_affiliates` table, use primary keys, declare `user_id` in `posts` to be a foreign key

Comment: Btw, `post_date` could be declared as `post_date NOT NULL default current_timestamp`

Comment: Sorry, `post_date timestamp NOT NULL default current_timestamp`

Answer (score 1):

You have a `user_id` on the posts table, so why not just use that?

```
select p.*
from posts p
where user_id = ?;
```

It is 100% unclear what the `posts` array is.  It is really confusing that it is documented as `post_id`s but the type is `text`.  There is no need for such an array, when you have the information in `posts`.

Comment: posts array is to hold post_id S i thought it would be faster to select post_id S from that array rather than selecting from posts table directly